# Filtering data from two or more tables in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, tablefilter

I have a few tables:

1. "DCDetails" table which contains the Master data for a few diagnostics centers.
2. "CompanyDetails" table which contains the Master data for Companies
3. "Investigation" table which contains the Investigations(meaning set of medical tests to be conducted)

These are my master tables.

I also have a few mapping tables:
1. "CompanyDCMap" table which contains the MAPPING of Company to Diagnostic centers
2. "InvestigationDCMap" table which contains the MAPPING of Investigation to Diagnostic centers(Or DC for short)

I have to filter a set of DC based on two criteria which are:

1. the DC belongs in the "CompanyDCMap" and
2. Out of the DC filtered in (1), it also belongs in the "InvestigationDCMap" table.

How do I write the query for this so that I get the DC which are in both CompanyDCMap and InvestigationDCMap given I have the primary keys of "CompanyDetails" and "Investigation" tables.

I have almost given up, I am unable to think of a query which filters two sets at the same time.

Kindly help me.

**UPDATE**
Schema: 
CompanyDetails table:

```
CompanyID(PRIMARY KEY), CompanyName(NVARCHAR(100))
   1                     Company1
   2                     Company2
   3                     Company3
```

Investigation Table:

```
InvestigationID(Primary key) , InvestigationName(NVARCHAR(100))
   1                               HIV+ Blood Test
   2                               TMT
   3                               Urine Test
```

DCDetails Table:

```
DCID(PRIMARY KEY), DCName(NVARCHAR(100))
   1                 DC1
   2                 DC2
   3                 DC3
```

CompanyDCMap table

```
   CompanyDCMapID(Primary key), CompanyID(Foreign key), DCId(Foreign Key)
          1                        1                       1
          2                        1                       2
          3                        2                       2
          4                        2                       3
          5                        3                       1
          6                        3                       3
```

InvestigationDCMap table

```
  InvestigationDCMapID(Primary Key), InvestigationID(Foreign Key), DCId(Foreign Key)
          1                                1                           1
          2                                1                           3
          3                                2                           2
          4                                2                           3
```

Expected Output of a query given CompanyID = 1 and InvestigationID = 2, SELECT DCId and DCName =

```
     DCId(Int)                   DCName(NVARCHAR(100))
      2                          DC2
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand there, I've introduced a schema, some details and the expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT d.DCID, d.DCName
FROM dbo.DCDetails AS d
INNER JOIN dbo.CompanyDCMap AS c
ON d.DCID = c.DCId
INNER JOIN dbo.InvestigationDCMap AS i
ON i.DCId = d.DCID;
```

To get "distinct" values, you can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.DCID, d.DCName
FROM dbo.DCDetails AS d
INNER JOIN dbo.CompanyDCMap AS c
ON d.DCID = c.DCId
INNER JOIN dbo.InvestigationDCMap AS i
ON i.DCId = d.DCID;
```

Or...

```
SELECT d.DCID, d.DCName
FROM dbo.DCDetails AS d
INNER JOIN dbo.CompanyDCMap AS c
ON d.DCID = c.DCId
INNER JOIN dbo.InvestigationDCMap AS i
ON i.DCId = d.DCID
GROUP BY d.DCID, d.DCName;
```

Better yet, since no relationships with the other tables are needed:

```
SELECT d.DCID, d.DCName
FROM dbo.DCDetails AS d
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.CompanyDCMap WHERE DCId = d.DCID)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.InvestigationDCMap WHERE DCId = d.DCID);
```

This will be a much more efficient query, but if you need other columns from the other tables, you'll need to revert to the join version.

Comment: Can you explain to me how this works? Since it does work! :-)

Comment: also, I can use `SELECT DISTINCT` to select the most distinct values

Comment: it is a primary key, but when I ran the query in my test sql server, I ran up with duplicate values, they probably came from the join expression